# As an individual Indian freelancer, do I have to create trade license & Current account?

Tags: bank-account, india

I am an individual Indian citizen. I am 23 years old. Currently, I am working as an individual freelancer in freelancer.com. I have a savings account in State Bank of India. I  do not have PAYPAL account. So after completing a job on those freelancer portal, if I get paid, can I transfer the money to my savings account via PayPal, and then can I en-cash the money? As I am individual, for working on those portal and earning money, is it essential for me to create a trade license and current account?
If you please help me for this, I shall be highly obliged.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not required to create a trade account or a current account.

If the payment is via Paypal, as per Indian laws, it would automatically get credited to your savings account in 7 days.

You would still need to declare this as income and pay tax accordingly.